# What did 'rap' mean in 1970?

Tags: meaning, historical-change, music

I found these folders (think pee chees) among a pile of school supplies. They reference "rap" in sort of a hippie look (and... is that John Wayne??), dated 1970. Presumably `wrap` is referring to `folder`, and `rap` is describing the type/style/design of the folder. Today, to me, `rap` is a type of music, but [this link](http://colemizestudios.com/how-did-rap-start/) suggests `rap` (the music format) started in 1973. So what did `rap` mean in 1970?

[image: front]
[image: back]
[image: inside with copyright date]

Comment: Looking at another [similar folder online](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vtg-1971-gene-bellos-rap-wrap-folder-1901197738) leads me to believe (given its placement on the linked folder) that this is the name of the style of the folder, and it may not have any real meaning besides being catchy.

Comment: Do you have a link??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a white, suburban, American, the most common usage of *rap* (aside from the literal meaning) in the 1970's was

> Slang. to talk or discuss, especially freely, openly, or volubly; chat.

([source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rap?s=t))

I guess they expect you to use the folder to keep notes about things you've been discussing?

Comment: It was used as a noun as well; a 'rap' could be a conversation or, often tediously, a monologue which was inspired in some way, e.g. by drugs, or political/religious conviction. Could be non-count - 'good rap flowed during the gathering'.

Answer (score 2):

1970s teenager here - "rap" meant talk, chat, etc., particularly about important or deep subjects.  My "trying to be hip" high school counselor offered "rap sessions" to the students to discuss their problems.

I think that the folder was probably meant mostly as a pun/wordplay.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It was just in the ‘60s that the original meaning “talk,chat” became popular and in the following decade the term  was used to refer to a style of music.

[Rap:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rap)

> ***talk informally, chat," 1929, popularized c. 1965 in African-American vernacular***, possibly first in Caribbean English and from British slang meaning "say, utter" (1879). ***Meaning "to perform rap music" is recorded by 1979***

(Etymonline)